# create a button using jsp that display a message

Tags: jsp

i have included the following statement for creation of a button. I want to print a message say,'hello' on same page below this button.

```
<input class="btn btn-success " type="submit" name="bulk_submission" value="hai b" />

the code gives me a button named hai b.
```

ON clicking this button,i want to display some message

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose we can call a simple  js function  and by using div id we can simply put content using **innerHTML**.
 Check the below code if you need further clarification please tell

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()   
{
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="Hello World";
    return false;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
<br/>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```